# What is the expected output for a port scanner in Java?

Tags: java, networking, port

So I wrote this basic port scanner:

```
    for(int p = 1; p < 65536; p++)
    {
        try{
            Socket socket = Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", p), 5);
            socket.close();
            System.out.printf("Port %d is open.\n", p);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

And the output was:

> Port 135 is open.
>
> Port 445 is open.
>
> Port 2869 is open.
>
> Port 5354 is open.
>
> Port 5357 is open.
>
> Port 8092 is open.
>
> Port 30000 is open.
>
> Port 49152 is open.
>
> Port 49153 is open.
>
> Port 49154 is open.
>
> Port 49155 is open.
>
> Port 49156 is open.
>
> Port 52000 is open.
>
> Port 53000 is open.

Is this normal? I looked for the answer, but couldn't find a case where the output was included. If these are incorrect or incomplete, I would like to know the expected output.

Comment: typo `Socket socket = new Socket();` ?

Comment: check output with netstat?

Comment: It was a typo, and I just checked netstat -a. All of them showed up except for 139 for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: port 139 - netbios (windows)